# JPA GroupBy multiple columns

Tags: java, jpa

I've to create a JPA query with a groupBy and I can write this:

```
cq.groupBy(root.get(MyObject_.field1));
```

but how to do it with multiple fields?

I think something like this:

```
List<???>  groupByList =   ArrayList<???>();
groupByList.add(root.get(MyObject_.field1))
groupByList.add(root.get(MyObject_.field2))

cq.groupBy(groupByList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the java docs for groupBy http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html :

you could use `cq.groupBy(groupByList);` or `cq.groupBy(root.get(MyObject_.field1), root.get(MyObject_.field2));`

Comment: it was so simple! Thx!